# First cohomology of a compact connected surface with boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is there a practical description for the first cohomology of $S_{g, b}$, the connected compact surface of genus $g$ and $b \geq 1$ boundary components?

Answer (score 1):

It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{2g+b+1}$. One can see this in a few ways.

One way is that one can cut $S_{g,b}$ along $2g+b+1$ pairwise disjoint arcs $A_1,...,A_{2g+b+a}$ with endpoints at the boundary to obtain a polygon. After assigning a transverse orientation to each $A_i$, the cohomology class corresponding to $A_i$ assigns, to each 1-cycle on $S_{g,b}$, the signed intersection number of that cycle with $A_i$.

Another way to see it is that $S_{g,b}$ deformation retracts onto a finite connected graph of rank $2g+b+1$, and so $H_1(S_{g,b}) \approx \mathbb{Z}^{2g+b+1}$. It follows that $H^1(S_{g,b}) \approx Hom(H_1(S_{g,b}),\mathbb{Z})$ is also $\approx \mathbb{Z}^{2g+b+1}$.